# member function nrow() in Rcpp

Tags: r, rcpp

let's go straightforward. Follow is the Rcpp example, so simple example. but some doubts come up.

```
src4 <- '
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::plugins("cpp11")]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
List rcpp_attributes(NumericVector v, NumericMatrix m, 
                     DataFrame df, List L) {

double nrows = 3;
double ncols = 3;
m.attr("dim") = NumericVector::create( nrows, ncols );

CharacterVector row_names = {"a", "b", "c"};
CharacterVector col_names = {"x", "y", "z"};
m.attr("dimnames") = List::create( row_names, col_names );

return List::create(
_["v.attr_names"] = v.attr("names"),     // Element names
_["v.names"] = v.names(),                // Element names
_["m.ncol"] = m.ncol(),                  // Number of columns
_["m.nrow"] = m.nrow(),                  // Number of rows
_["m.attr_dim"] = m.attr("dim"), 
_["m.attr_dimnames"] = m.attr("dimnames"),
_["df.attr_names"] = df.attr("names"),        // column names
_["df.attr_row.names"] = df.attr("row.names"), // row names
_["L.names"] = L.names(),            // Element names
_["m"] = m
);
}
'
sourceCpp(code = src4)
rcpp_attributes(c("s" = 1, "u" = 2, "k" = 3),
                matrix(1:9, 9, 1),
                data.frame(a = c("a1", "a2"),
                           b = c(   1, 3)),
                list("a" = c(1), "b" = c(1,2), "c" = c(1,2,3)))
```

Returning results are listed below:

```
## $v.attr_names
## [1] "s" "u" "k"
## 
## $v.names
## [1] "s" "u" "k"
## 
## $m.ncol
## [1] 3
## 
## $m.nrow
## [1] 9
## 
## $m.attr_dim
## [1] 3 3
## 
## $m.attr_dimnames
## $m.attr_dimnames[[1]]
## [1] "a" "b" "c"
## 
## $m.attr_dimnames[[2]]
## [1] "x" "y" "z"
## 
## 
## $df.attr_names
## [1] "a" "b"
## 
## $df.attr_row.names
## [1] 1 2
## 
## $L.names
## [1] "a" "b" "c"
## 
## $m
##   x y z
## a 1 4 7
## b 2 5 8
## c 3 6 9
```

From above, we can see that, $m.ncol returns 3, it's right. However,
the element $m.nrow returns 9. And I think it should be 3.
I hope someone who write Rcpp codes can tell me the reason?
Thanks!~~

Comment: I am not sure I agree that this is a "simple" example in the sense of "please post the simpletes reproducible example.  I don;t have time to work through something more complex than it needs to be.  But maybe someone else will.

Comment: So glancing at this ... you expect the dimension attribute change (to 3x3) to propagate to the values from when the matrix was instantiated (as 9x1).  And that does not happen.  End of story.  I am not sure I care about this as a bug.  If you modify your object during its lifetime, you are responsible of consequence and side effects.

Comment: yes, what you said is what I expected. But until now, I still donot know why this issue comes up.

Comment: Follow the code. The member functions access elements sets _at construction_ and when you change the attribute `dim` there is no connection between those two parts.